# How to prevent child element from inheriting CSS styles

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` element with a `<p>` element inside:

```
<div style="font-size:10pt; color:red;">
    This is my Parent Div.
    <p>This is my Child Paragraph.</p>
    My parent Div Ends Here.
</div>
```

How can I prevent my paragraph from inheriting the CSS properties set to the `<div>`?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the best way is to just over right the styles that the `<p>` element is inheriting:

So in your CSS file, which you should be using instead of inline styles:

```
.parent-div {
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: red;
}

.child-paragraph {
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child node -

```
<p style="font-size:12pt; color:black;">This is my child</p>
```

Just set the inline style to whatever you want.

Comment: This will be possible only when very few styles are set. Currently my Focus Node is Paragraph and i will be having different parent Nodes. So i want to avoid the styling of all Parent Nodes and Keep whatever i have set to my Paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `>` selector in CSS to select the immediate child `p` of `div`.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e58Ta/)

```
div > p {
    font-size:1.2 em;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to make all the styling to default value. As you said paragraph styling we can set.But all values i want to set to the default.How can i set that.

Comment: What do you mean by `all values`? Please elaborate a little?

Comment: All CSS style informations like backgroundColor, image etc... Currently i am making a class and with all style information adn trying to add that class to the required location