# Working with gmaps on meteor

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is there a way to call a template on other template, but excluding it from the CSS selectors and all?

This does not work, the `{{> map_template}}` looks weird:

```
<template name="main">
  <div class="containerMain">   
    <div id="bl-main" class="bl-main"> 
      <section>
        <div class="bl-box">
          <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="bl-content">
          <h2>Pa' Donde Menu</h2>                                
            {{#each mostrarEvento}} 
              {{> Evento}}
            {{/each}} 
            {{> map_template}}
        </div>
        <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works:

```
<template name="main">
  {{> map_template}}
  <div class="containerMain"> 
    <div id="bl-main" class="bl-main"> 
      <section>
        <div class="bl-box">
          <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="bl-content">
          <h2>Pa' Donde Menu</h2>                                
          {{#each mostrarEvento}} 
            {{> Evento}}
          {{/each}}              
        </div>
        <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

So is there a way to use `{{> map_Template}}` inside the `<div class="containerMain">`, but without applying the CSS and all that stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a web whiz, but off the top of my head, you need to create a new template for the `{{> map_template}}`. Make sure to name the class inside map_template and then create a css template inside your style.css or wherever you are getting your CSS from.

Your CSS should end up something like:

```
.map-template{
    //style stuff
}
```

Where {map-template} matches your class name.

I used this question to try to piece together a solution: [How to prevent child element from inheriting CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376444/how-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-css-styles)

Sorry if that isn't quite what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi griffin, the map actually its showing nice and all, i think the problem its destroy and init the map on each modal, but since Google maps don't have a destroy contractor or something, so im stuck haha